# Eclipse Android project not given deprecated compiler warnings

Tags: android, eclipse, deprecated

I am using eclipse

```
Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149
```

and have run into an issue where I am **not** getting compiler warnings / errors for using **deprecated** constructors in Android projects.

For example in a Java proj the line

```
Date date = new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0);
```

will throw a compiler error (as i have set it up in prefs), but in an Android project it will be fine and wont warn / error. This has been deprecated in Android since API level 1 .

[public Date (int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Anyone know why this may be? Both my projects have Java 1.6 SDK set. This is quite annoying for me!